# Getting all post/page IDs related to a soon-to-be-deleted tag/cat

Tags: hooks

When deleting a tag, category or other term I would like to get the IDs of the posts that are related to the term before deletion. Wordpress uses wp_delete_term, which is found in taxonomy.php, to delete a term. In this function the earliest hook is "delete_term_taxonomy". However, it seems like the relationships are already deleted before this hook fires.

I would like to make this query:

```
SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $id
```

This would normally return all the post ids related to a term (category/tag/etc). Is there any other hook I can use? Or maybe a hack?

Answer (score 0):

> In this function the earliest hook is "delete_term_taxonomy". However, it seems like the relationships are already deleted before this hook fires.

According to the source, `'delete_term_taxonomy'` runs just before deletion and `'deleted_term_taxonomy'` runs just after. There are other things going on before this code, like the child relationships are changed.

```
do_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
$wpdb->delete( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $tt_id ) );
do_action( 'deleted_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
```

Are you sure you were not using `'deleted_term_taxonomy'` by mistake?

> Is there any other hook I can use?

If the taxonomy is hierarchical, `'edit_term_taxonomies'` and `'edited_term_taxonomies'` run first:

```
do_action( 'edit_term_taxonomies', $edit_tt_ids );
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, compact( 'parent' ), array( 'parent' => $term_obj->term_id) + compact( 'taxonomy' ) );
do_action( 'edited_term_taxonomies', $edit_tt_ids );
```

Comment: If the term was hierarchical, it would work. However, it should work in both cases. Wordpress is making the exact same query I want to do (on line 1805 in taxonomy.php) and then goes through them all in a foreach loop. If i try to make the query right after that loop, it doesn't work. So something is happening there. 'delete_term_taxonomy' runs before deletion of the term itself, but not the relationships it has. Those seem to be deleted before that.

Comment: Upon further digging, it seems like I can use the hook 'wp_get_object_terms'.